# Why dcast round my float numbers?

Tags: r, dcast

I have one data frame as:

```
> head(df)
     nome   Class_Name area_class       date
1 Arataca agropecuaria    25.7751 1973-07-26
2 Arataca         agua     0.2918 1973-07-26
3 Arataca       bosque     0.0207 1973-07-26
4 Arataca       bosque     3.9335 1973-07-26
5 Arataca         mata    69.9513 1973-07-26
6 Arataca solo exposto     0.0276 1973-07-26
```

When I converted it with dcast function the value column not keep as float number:

```
dcast(df, nome+date~Class_Name, value.var = "area_class")
            nome       date agropecuaria agua bosque mata solo exposto
1              Arataca 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
2            Buerarema 1973-07-26            1    0      2    1            1
3              Camacan 1973-07-26            1    0      1    1            0
4               Camamu 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
5            Igrapiúna 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
6               Ilhéus 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
7              Itabuna 1973-07-26            1    0      2    1            1
8              Itacaré 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
9              Ituberá 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
10               Maraú 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
11        Nilo Peçanha 1973-07-26            1    0      2    1            0
12 São José da Vitória 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            0
13                 Una 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
14             Uruçuca 1973-07-26            1    1      2    1            1
```

Why "area_class" which is a numeric class not keep as float number when I converted it?

Comment: Are u getting the `length` because of duplicates?

Comment: There are duplicates. I've solved with aggregate function. Thks

Comment: You could use `dcast(df, nome+date~Class_Name, value.var = "area_class", mean)`

Comment: Yes. I did so. Thks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output in OP's post could be because of the duplicate rows which makes the `dcast` `fun.aggregate` to do the `length` as the default option.  Inorder to prevent this, either create a sequence column or aggregate the `value.var` (depends on the requirement)

```
dcast(df, nome+date~Class_Name, value.var = "area_class", fun.aggregate = mean)
```